# Python tarfile and excludes

Tags: python, tarfile

This is an excerpt from Python's documentation:

> If exclude is given it must be a function that takes one filename
>   argument and returns a boolean value. Depending on this value the
>   respective file is either excluded (True) or added (False).

I must admit that I have no idea what that means.

Furthermore:

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The exclude parameter is deprecated,
>   please use the filter parameter instead. For maximum portability,
>   filter should be used as a keyword argument rather than as a
>   positional argument so that code won’t be affected when exclude is
>   ultimately removed.

Ok... and the definition for "filter":

> If filter is specified it must be a function that takes a TarInfo
>   object argument and returns the changed TarInfo object. If it instead
>   returns None the TarInfo object will be excluded from the archive.

... back to square one :)

What I really need is a way to pass an array (or a ":" delimited string) of excludes to the tarfile.add.

I would not mind if you try to explain what those passages from PyDocs ment.

P.S.:

This just crossed my mind:

- Making an array of a list of source dir content
- popping excludes
- doing tar.add on individual array members that are left

But, I'd like it done in a more cultured way

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> If exclude is given it must be a function that takes one filename
>   argument and returns a boolean value. Depending on this value the
>   respective file is either excluded (True) or added (False).

For example, if you wanted to exclude all filenames beginning with the letter 'a', you'd do something like...

```
def exclude_function(filename):
    if filename.startswith('a'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

mytarfile.add(..., exclude=exclude_function)
```

For your case, you'd want something like...

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['README', 'INSTALL', '.cvsignore']

def exclude_function(filename):
    if filename in EXCLUDE_FILES:
        return True
    else:
        return False

mytarfile.add(..., exclude=exclude_function)
```

...which can be reduced to...

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['README', 'INSTALL', '.cvsignore']

mytarfile.add(..., exclude=lambda x: x in EXCLUDE_FILES)
```

**Update**

TBH, I wouldn't worry too much about the deprecation warning, but if you want to use the new `filter` parameter, you'd need something like...

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['README', 'INSTALL', '.cvsignore']

def filter_function(tarinfo):
    if tarinfo.name in EXCLUDE_FILES:
        return None
    else:
        return tarinfo

mytarfile.add(..., filter=filter_function)
```

...which can be reduced to...

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['README', 'INSTALL', '.cvsignore']

mytarfile.add(..., filter=lambda x: None if x.name in EXCLUDE_FILES else x)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! But what about that bit that exclude is deprecated?

Comment: Great! I will stick to filter, just to be on the safe side. Thank you so much!

Comment: Almost 5 years later and this just answered my question.  Thanks @Aya!

Comment: How to exclude subdirectories?