# Excluding directories from tarfile module

Tags: python, tarfile

I am trying to tar the contents of a directory using the tarfile module.

Say this directory, called 'A', has several subdirectories, 'a' and 'a1' etc...
Is there a way to exclude these directories from the tarfile object when trying to add?
For example, I have a list of files to exclude, which I put in the list:

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['README', '.gitignore']
```

I can exclude these following a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000794/python-tarfile-and-excludes) found here. However, can this method be altered to exclude directories or is there another way in which it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the example from the other answer you've posted, can you not do:

```
def exclude_function(filename):
    return os.path.isdir(filename):

mytarfile.add(..., exclude=exclude_function)
```

Or to simplify, perhaps:

```
mytarfile.add(..., exclude=os.path.isdir)
```

Using filter:

```
def filter_function(tarinfo):
   if os.path.isdir(tarinfo.name):
        return None
   return tarinfo

mytarfile.add(..., filter=filter_function)
```

Comment: For reference, version 3.7 has removed support for the `exclude` param. You must use `filter`. https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/4f76fb16b7e00dac91ea4089a28e06e8720e3294