# Creating archive with shutil.make_archive() while excluding some path(s)

Tags: python, python-2.7, archive, shutil

Is there a way to have `shutil.make_archive` exclude some child directories, or alternatively, is there a way to append directories to a single archive through `shutil`?

**Examples are fun**:

```
/root
  /workingDir
      /dir1
      /dir2
          /dirA
          /dirB
      /dir3
```

Suppose I wanted to create an archive from within `workingDir` that included everything *except* for `dirA` -- how could I do this? Is it possible without writing a method to loop through the entire tree?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is possible with directly with shutil. It is possible to do it with tarfile (which is used by shutil internally anyway)

[Tarfile.add](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.add) has a filter argument that you can use precisely for this purpose.

See also this answer: [Python tarfile and excludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000794/python-tarfile-and-excludes)

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['dir2/dirA']
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", "w:gz")
tar.add("workingDir", filter=lambda x: None if x.name in EXCLUDE_FILES else x)
tar.close()
```

Comment: I experienced that this code was not excluding dirA, when I tried it with a similar folder structure