# Python: using filter in tarfile

Tags: python, filter, tarfile

I am writing a backup script which uses tarfile module. I am a beginner in python. Here is part of my script - 
So I have a list of paths that need to be archived in tar.gz. seeing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000794/python-tarfile-and-excludes), I came up with following. Now archive gets created but the files with .tmp and .data extension aren't getting omitted. I am using python 3.5

```
L = [path1, path2, path3, path4, path5]
exclude_files = [".tmp", ".data"]
# print L

def filter_function(tarinfo):
     if tarinfo.name in exclude_files:
          return None
     else:
          return tarinfo

with tarfile.open("backup.tar.gz", "w:gz") as tar:
     for name in L:
        tar.add(name, filter=filter_function)
```

Answer (score 2):

you're comparing the extensions vs the full names.

Just use `os.path.splitext` and compare the extension:

```
 if os.path.splitext(tarinfo.name)[1] in exclude_files:
```

shorter: rewrite your `add` line with a ternary expression and a lambda to avoid the helper function:

```
tar.add(name, filter=lambda tarinfo: None if os.path.splitext(tarinfo.name)[1] in exclude_files else tarinfo)
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked. I have a question, if I have to add a path to the exclusion list, how would that work?

Comment: that would be a relative path then. You'd perform a `os.path.dirname(tarinfo.name)` and compare with the directory you want to exclude. I suggest that you print the 2 parts you're comparing in your function so you see if there's a chance that they match. Had you do it in the first place you'd have seen that you were comparing extensions with the full name.

Comment: I wrote this instead 

`L = [path1, path2, path3, path4, path5]
exclude_files = [".tmp", ".data", "/media/Data/Textfiles/Linux", "/media/Data/Textfiles/Old/Pushbullet"]


def exclude_function(filename):
    if filename in exclude_files or os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in exclude_files:
        return True
    else:
        return False

with tarfile.open("backup.tar.gz", "w:gz") as tar:
     for name in L:
        tar.add(name, exclude=exclude_function)`

Comment: Somehow I am not getting the filter part. The above code works for every extension file or path mentioned in exclude. and about the shorter code, I only started learning python a few days ago, So i am writing code as expanded as possible. Once I get familiar with the language more, I will try to be more concise.

Comment: make 2 lists: one for path exclusions and one for extension exclusions. And I doubt that the tarfile contains absolute paths. Print them in your filter function to see what the filter takes in input.