# How to exclude specific subfolders from the generated tar file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar, subdirectory, tarfile

I am using Python 3 with the `tarfile` module to compress some folders (with subfolders). What I need to do: to set a couple of subfolders to be excluded from the final tar file.

For example, say my folders looked like:

```
dir/
├── subdirA
│   ├── subsubdirA1
│   │   └── fileA11.txt
│   │   └── fileA12.txt
│   ├── subsubdirA2
│   │   └── fileA21.txt
│   │   └── fileA22.txt
│   └── fileA.txt
├── subdirB
│   ├── subsubdirB1
│   │   └── fileB11.txt
│   │   └── fileA12.txt
│   ├── subsubdirB2
│   │   └── fileB21.txt
│   │   └── fileB22.txt
│   └── fileB.txt
└── main.txt
```

Now, I say I wanted to include everything in `dir/` except the contents of `subsubdirA2` and of `subsubdirB2`. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16000963/8583858), I have tried:

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['/subdirA/subsubdirA2', '/subdirB/subsubdirB2']
mytarfile.add(..., filter=lambda x: None if x.name in EXCLUDE_FILES else x)
```

Or:

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['/subdirA/subsubdirA2/*', '/subdirB/subsubdirB2/*']
mytarfile.add(..., filter=lambda x: None if x.name in EXCLUDE_FILES else x)
```

Or:

```
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['/subdirA/subsubdirA2/*.*', '/subdirB/subsubdirB2/*.*']
mytarfile.add(..., filter=lambda x: None if x.name in EXCLUDE_FILES else x)
```

I also tried variants of the three options above where the subfolder paths started without `/` or with `dir` or with `/dir`. None worked - all the time, everything within `dir` was included.

How could I correctly exclude specific subfolders from a tar file I want to generate? If a different module/library is required instead of `tarfile`, that is fine.

Comment: is for linux??...because maybe with subprocess (library for shell) and python can work

Comment: I think `x.name` is not matched with any items in the `EXCLUDE_FILES` list since `/file/path/*` is considered as a file with name `*` and not a regular expression match

Comment: @saurjog but that does not apply to the other examples I gave, right?

Comment: @JorgetMillani, apologies for the late reply. Please see my answer below. My earlier comment applies to all the examples that you'd given.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find reference about tarfile the way you need, but you can use thread and include shell command like this:

```
import subprocess

exclude=['dir/subdirA/subsubdirA2','dir/subdirA/subsubdirA1','dir/subdirA/text.tx']
excludeline=''
for x in exclude:
    excludeline += ' --exclude '+x
# cmd has tar command
cmd='tar -czvf dir.tar dir  '+ excludeline
print(cmd)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result=process.stdout.readlines()
# All files were compressed
if len(result) >= 1:
    for line in result:
        print(line.decode("utf-8"))
```

Where cmd has value in this example :

```
cmd = tar -czvf dir.tar dir   --exclude dir/subdirA/subsubdirA2 --exclude dir/subdirA/subsubdirA1 --exclude dir/subdirA/text.tx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `EXCLUDE_FILES` that you are using should be matched against the file names with pattern matching. Here is how I would do that:

```
import re, os    
EXCLUDE_FILES = ['/subdirA/subsubdirA2/*', '/subdirB/subsubdirB2/*']
pattern = '(?:% s)' % '|'.join(EXCLUDE_FILES) #form a pattern string
```

For using a filter against the pattern we'll use `re.match`,

```
mytarfile.add(..., filter=lambda x: None if re.match(pattern, x.name) else x)
```

We exclude the file if `file.name` matches any of the patterns specified in `EXCLUDE_FILES`. Hope this helps.